# Chrome Extension: Failed to start native messaging host

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-native-messaging

I'm developing a Chrome extension using Native Messaging technology.
The extension works but on some PC I get an error:

> Failed to start native messaging host

Some (not all) of those PCs are running Windows 7 and Windows XP:

- Windows 7: the PC has a lock icon on the user folder `C:\Users`. I can fix it as per the [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17117/remove-the-lock-icon-from-a-folder-in-windows-7/) and restart the PC to make my extension work.
- Windows XP: I have not found any solution for this error.

According to [nativeMessaging documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-debugging) I think the problem is related to filesystem security permissions of `chrome.exe` file and native host application file.

I've asked many times about this problem on other groups and searched on google but haven't found a solution.

1. How to check the permissions of `chrome.exe` file or native host application file are okay?
2. Any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: So far it looks like a rare problem not related to your extension. Anyway there's nothing you can do about it *before* launching the native app because Chrome doesn't expose any API to check filesystem permissions.

Comment: Also the comments in the linked thread say that you have a typo: registry path should contain `Software`, not `Sofware`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks wOxxOm! Have you seen my case? Have you solution for this problem in win xp?

Answer (score 0):

Xan comment is correct. --enable-native-messaging not needed.

**Udpated:**
Finally, this answer [Failed to start native messaging host on Windows, "COMSPEC is not set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552699/failed-to-start-native-messaging-host-on-windows-comspec-is-not-set) hellped me.

Need add `ComSpec` in System variables.

Comment: 1) Native messaging is enabled by default. 2) That flag is certainly malformed, there are no flags with `--` in the middle. 3) I can find no evidence this is actually a flag that exists in current Chrome versions.