# Failed to start native messaging host on Windows, "COMSPEC is not set"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a chrome extension that communicates with a native messaging host to get some data.

The issue is, when I launch the Chrome browser via the shortcut or via the pinned shortcut in the taskbar, the extension is not able to connect to the host. I always get the error:

> Failed to start native messaging host.

However, if I launch the `chrome.exe` via command prompt, everything works fine.

Things I tried with no success:

- The taskbar shortcut has no extra flags. The target field has the
  following value: `"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`
- I tried with the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.company.extension`
- I tried with the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.company.extension`
- I tried with the registry entry under
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.company.extension`
- Tried launching the `chrome.exe` as administrator from the file explorer.

**Update:**

I added the flag `--enable-logging --v=1` to the shortcut to enable logging and when I launch it I get the following output in the console:

```
[11036:4160:0302/113902.866:ERROR:native_process_launcher_win.cc(140)] COMSPEC is not set
[11036:11856:0302/113902.882:ERROR:native_process_launcher_win.cc(140)] COMSPEC is not set
```

**Update**

Upon investigating the `chrome.exe` process via Process Monitor, I found that there is no `COMSPEC` environment variable available to it when it is spawned via `explorer`.

Is there anything else that I can try or something that I am missing here?

Comment: This error means Chrome at least [tried to launch](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/messaging/native_message_process_host.cc?l=114&rcl=c463181850479e23e89ebd766fbe1fa2990d9d51) the host so you may see something related to `Process Create` in [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).

Comment: One should also [enable and examine Chrome logs](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging). Possible thought: what a shortcut changes is the working directory.

Comment: @Xan Yes I got an error in the console by adding the logging flags. I have updated the question with the error.

Comment: @wOxxOm I am working with Process monitor. There is lot of output for `chrome.exe` process in it, so I am trying to create better filters. I'll update you if I find something via it.

Comment: It seems like your environment variables are somehow misconfigured. `%COMSPEC%` should be an environment variable pointing at `cmd`. To clarify, what kind of native host are you using?

Comment: See https://crbug.com/387233 and [other bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=COMSPEC+component%3APlatform%3EExtensions) for COMSPEC

Comment: Upon doing `set COMSPEC` in cmd I get the following result  `COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`. So I suppose it is configured correctly.

Comment: @Xan Unfortunately it is my other colleague who developed the native host. So I don't have much information on it. All I have is an exe file of the host.

Comment: @PrerakSola That's exactly the point: you CAN launch chrome from `cmd` and it works properly. But the variable isn't properly set for processes spawned by `explorer` itself. Please check environment variables of a running instance of Chrome with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) (I seem to remember it shows that).

Comment: @Xan Yes you are right. While launching the process via explorer there is no `COMSPEC` environment variable in the list for `chrome.exe` process. So is there anything that can be done to correct this? Because I don't remember altering this anytime in the past.

Comment: See if the variable is set in System variables at `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` (run from admin command prompt). It it isn't, set it and logout or reboot to test. If that helps, I'll make it into an answer.

Comment: @Xan Yeah that was it. It is working fine now. You can make that an answer. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the log, Chrome stumbles to start an external process, since `COMSPEC`, an [environment variable pointing normally to `cmd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976142.aspx), is unset:

```
[11036:4160:0302/113902.866:ERROR:native_process_launcher_win.cc(140)] COMSPEC is not set
```

The behavior is different for launching Chrome from `cmd` itself, since it sets the variable for itself (ans spawned processes).

This can be confirmed by inspecting the Chrome process with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx).

One can run `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` as admin (e.g. from admin command line) to open the environment variable settings.
Alternatively, the dialog can be navigated to from Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced > Environment Variables...

`ComSpec` is usually set in System variables to

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
```

Adjust as necessary for your system install. For this setting to apply, you need to log out and log back in, or better yet restart the system.